# GetBytes() returns negative number

Tags: java, string

```
*"Hätten Hüte ein ä im Namen, wären sie möglicherweise keine Hüte mehr, sondern Häte."
 72  -61  -92  116  116  101  ...*
```

GetBytes() returns negative number (-61, () )  at the char 'ä'.

How to get the normal ascii value?

Comment: `ä` has no ascii value, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: i'm writing a base64 encoder, so i need to handle that char
what should i do?

Comment: @user2147674: If you're starting with *text*, why are you using base64? Base64 is meant to encode *binary* data. (And why are you writing a base64 encoder when so many working versions already available?)

Comment: It's for my computer science class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> GetBytes() returns negative number (-61, () ) at the char 'ä'.

Well `getBytes()` is going to use the platform default encoding, unless you specify an encoding, which you should. I would recommend UTF-8 normally. For example, in Java 7:

```
byte[] data = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

`byte` in Java is unfortunately signed - but you can *think* of it as being just 8 bits. If you want to see the effective unsigned, just use:

```
int unsigned = someByte & 0xff;
```

> How to get the normal ascii value?

That character doesn't exist in ASCII. All ASCII characters are in the range U+0000 to U+007F.

Comment: I'm using OS X, so should i set the encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: @user2147674: Well it depends on what you're trying to do with the data, but if you're in control of whatever's reading the data too, UTF-8 is a good bet as it's probably the most commonly-supported full-Unicode encoding.

Comment: ok, can i set the default encoding in eclipse or do I have to use getBytes("UTF-8"); ?

Comment: @user2147674: You could set the default encoding at the start of your program, but I'd *strongly* recommend that you specify the encoding explicitly every time instead. If you're using Java 7 I'd encourage you to use `StandardCharsets` instead of a string constant.

Comment: @JonSkeet: How you can be always right? :P Anyway great answer

Comment: Thanks for the note note on unsigned value.  I could not figure out why python bytearray and my version were giving different byte values.

Answer (score 2):

1. Some bytes are negative because `byte`s are signed in Java, just like `int`s, `short`s and `long`s. The easiest way to undo it is to use `& 255` - example code: `int fixed_byte = original_byte & 255;`.
2. There is no normal ASCII value for `ä` because `ä` is not part of ASCII.
3. `getBytes` does not use ASCII.
4. On your system, `getBytes` seems to be using UTF-8. `getBytes` does not use the same encoding on all systems. If you specifically want UTF-8, use `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.
5. If you look closely, you'll notice that `ä` is actually encoded as *two* bytes in UTF-8: -61 and -92. After fixing them to not be negative, these are 195 and 164.
6. Why use bytes at all? A `char` can hold any character from the Basic Multilingual Plane, including the character `ä`. (If not for historical mistakes, a `char` would be able to hold any character. It's too late to fix it now.)